# Azure storage is corrupting files after upload?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-node-sdk

I'm trying to upload images to azure storage like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", blobUrl);
xhr.responseType = "text";//force the HTTP response, response-type header to be blob
xhr.onload = function () {
    blobService.createBlockBlobFromText('taskcontainer', 'myblob', xhr.responseText,  {contentSettings: {contentType: "image/bmp"}}, (error, result, response)=>{
    })
}
xhr.send();
```

If I upload something simple like a text file with 'abc' it uploads fine, however if I try to upload something like an image it seems to get corrupted, the diff shows the file after it was uploaded to azure (left) and before it was uploaded: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2121021/35678518-cb006af4-07a7-11e8-963d-2bb8b45aba26.png

I'm not sure what's going on exactly and have been trying to solve this for a while now...

Comment: Could it be because you're setting the response type as text (`xhr.responseType = "text"`) and reading the binary content as text?

Comment: The responseText size is correct for the bitmap when it's uploaded, after it's on azure storage the uploaded file is somehow bigger so I don't think it's that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd need to set [`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) to `arraybuffer` when you receive binary data via `XMLHttpRequest` object.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", blobUrl);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function () {
    blobService.createBlockBlobFromText('taskcontainer', 'myblob', new Uint8Array(xhr.response),  {contentSettings: {contentType: "image/bmp"}}, (error, result, response) => {
    })
}
xhr.send();
```